# Understanding the matrix output of Tfidfvectorizer in Sklearn

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm having trouble interpreting the matrix output for the Tfidf vectorizer.

Given

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features=10000,
                         min_df=2, stop_words='english',
                         use_idf=True)


X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
```

If I were to look at the output of `X_train_tfidf`, am I looking at a matrix that is structured like:

Column 1 corresponds to document 1 where its elements are tfidf scores of the 10000 features, Column 2 corresponds to document 2... and so on?

Comment: I was just about to post this same question...

Comment: Is the [tutorial not good enough](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're seeing output similar to this:

```
(0, 18)       0.424688479366
(0, 6)        0.424688479366
(0, 4)        0.424688479366
(0, 14)       0.239262081323
(0, 17)       0.202366335916
(0, 5)        0.424688479366
(0, 1)        0.424688479366
(1, 17)       0.184426607226
(1, 8)        0.387039944282
(1, 15)       0.387039944282
(1, 0)        0.387039944282
(1, 2)        0.387039944282
(1, 13)       0.387039944282
(1, 7)        0.387039944282
(1, 11)       0.259205161463
(2, 14)       0.313686744222
(2, 17)       0.530628478217
(2, 9)        0.556791722552
(2, 16)       0.556791722552
(3, 14)       0.346483013718
(3, 17)       0.293053113789
(3, 11)       0.411875926253
(3, 10)       0.61500486583
(3, 3)        0.496182053366
(4, 14)       0.346483013718
(4, 17)       0.293053113789
(4, 11)       0.411875926253
(4, 3)        0.496182053366
(4, 12)       0.61500486583
```

Assume general form: (A,B) C

A: Document index
B: Specific word-vector index
C: TFIDF score for word B in document A

This is a sparse matrix.  It indicates the tfidf score for all non-zero values in the word vector for each document.